# QSqlRelationalModel: After I call setRelation(...), the column in the model seem to be replaced by the column in the foreign table

Tags: qt, qsqlrelationaltablemodel

After setRelation(...), How can I get **the original value of the column** which seems have already been replaced by the column in the foreign table?

Here's my code:

Table "record" contains "recordId integer, bookId integer, bookName varchar, author varchar, 
**genre integer**, userId integer, userName varchar, borrowDate date, returnDate date, recordState integer".

Table "genres" contains "id integer primary key, genre varchar".

```
    QSqlRelationalTableModel *model = new QSqlRelationalTableModel;

    model->setTable("record");

    model->setRelation(4, QSqlRelation("genres", "id", "genre"));

    QSqlRecord bookRecord = model->record(0);

    QVariant value = bookRecord->value(4);
```

The line `QVariant value = bookRecord->value(4);` **returns contents in table "genres" which is QString instead of the original value genre in table "record" which is integer**

Here I want to assign the original value of bookRecord at section 4 to the QVariant variable value. How can I do it?

Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I used a not much elegant method to solve the problem.

I create a new `QSqlquery` object and query the original table directly.

It's not very smart, but anyway, the problem is solved.